# Generate ListView items from a number determined at runtime, rather than from DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, web-applications, webforms

I'm trying to have a `ListView` control display as many forms as a user likes, depending on how many times the user clicks an "`Add`" button. Basically, I *do not* want to bind the `ListView` to a `DataSource`, but rather add an `ItemTemplate` programmatically 1, 5, 13 or however many times I like. For testing purposes lets say I want to add 13 forms to a `ListView`. Is there any way to do this? I'm using `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

ListView:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate><br /><%# Eval("Value") %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Value"] = "first record";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Value"] = "second record";
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    //other records if needed
    ListView1.DataSource = dt;
    ListView1.DataBind();
```

You can use also list of objects instead of DataTable.